# Use jQuery to display controls only in case of hidden content

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow

I want to display controls to scroll the contents of a div only in case of overflow. I'm not sure I have the syntax right - any help would be appreciated.

[My JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dmtyontn/)

My HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="line-1">Line 1</div>
        <div class="line-2">Line 2</div>
        <div class="line-3">Line 3</div>
        <div class="line-4">Line 4</div>
        <div class="line-5">Line 5</div>
        <div class="line-6">Line 6</div>
        <div class="line-7">Line 7</div>
        <div class="line-8">Line 8</div>
        <div class="line-9">Line 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="line-1">Line 1</div>
        <div class="line-2">Line 2</div>
        <div class="line-3">Line 3</div>
        <div class="line-4">Line 4</div>
        <div class="line-5">Line 5</div>
        <div class="line-6">Line 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
if ((".content").offsetHeight < (".content").scrollHeight)
    {
        $( ".container .buttons" ).append( "<button>Up</button><button>Down</button>" );
    }
```

My CSS

```
.container
    {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

.content
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but there are a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. `(".content")` is not valid code, make sure to call it with jquery: `$('.content')`.
2. offsetHeight and scrollHeight are native javascript properties, so you can't call them on a jquery object, but you can on a native HTML element. If you wish to use jQuery syntax, you can write it like this: `$(".content")[0].offsetHeight`
3. I wrapped everything in an `each` block so that not all buttons classes get an update when just 1 container is overflowing.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmtyontn/4/) showing the complete solution.

It's also worth noting that if you need to support below IE8, you may have compatibility issues [as seen in this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

first you need to remove `height` from `.content`
and we check if `.content` is greater then `100` if yes We set `100px` height to that div and append buttons.

Your **JS** would be like this

```
$(".content").each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 100){
        $(this).css("height","100px");
        $(this).next(".buttons").append( "<button>Up</button><button>Down</button>" );
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dmtyontn/3/)**

Comment: Imo, this is not a prefered solution, since you're using fixed height so it won't work when the CSS changes.

Comment: @PoeHah `OP` has also given the fixed height to `.content` div in `CSS`, so i used that as refernce